# Estou tendo problemas com o appendChild em javascript

Tags: javascript

Código HTML

```html
<div class="larguraetapa pBacklog">
    <div class="theadWspace">
        <p class="tituloSkrun">Product Backlog</p>
    </div>
    <div class="etapa">
        <div class="tbodyWspace">
            <div id="pBacklog" class="containerCards">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="bto-pBacklog" class="buttonNewCard">+ Adicionar cartão</button>
</div>
```

O sistema deve incluir na div class containerCards uma div com um textarea dentro quando o botão "+Adicionar Cartão" for clicado, após o clique ele de ser substituído pelo botão "Criar Card" e quando o botão "Criar Card" for clicado ele deve ser substituído pelo botão "+Adicionar Cartão".

Obs. o sistema tem mais de uma estrutura com classes diferentes e estou diferenciando elas escutando o click do mouse, que retorna o id do botão clicado e através dessa informação seleciono os botões e as estruturas nas quais as automações devem acontecer!

O sistema está acusando o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading
> 'appendChild')
> at criaCard (31)
> at HTMLDivElement.selecionaBotao (13)

e não estou conseguindo remover a class invisivel do botão "+Adicionar Card"

Código Javascript

```js
const escutaClick = document.querySelector('.workSpace');

escutaClick.addEventListener('click', function selecionaBotao(click) {
    var idBotao = click.target.id;
    var idContainer = idBotao.replace('bto-', '');
    // Remove o botão Adicionar cartão
    var btoAddCard = document.getElementById(idBotao);
    btoAddCard.classList.add("invisivel");
    //=============>Criar estrutura do card<===============
    var { criarDiv, selecionarDiv } = criaDiv(idContainer);
    criaCard(criarDiv, selecionarDiv);
    CriaBto(idContainer);
});

//Cria elemento div
function criaDiv(idContainer) {
    var selecionarDiv = document.getElementById(idContainer);
    var criarDiv = document.createElement("div");
    criarDiv.setAttribute("class", "card");
    return { criarDiv, selecionarDiv };
}

// Cria elemento textarea
function criaCard(criarDiv, selecionarDiv) {
    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textarea.setAttribute("class", "textCard");
    textarea.setAttribute("placeholder", "Descreva a atividade");
    textarea.setAttribute("onfocus", "this.selectionStart");
    criarDiv.appendChild(textarea).focus();
    selecionarDiv.appendChild(criarDiv);
}

// Criar botão Criar card
function CriaBto(idContainer) {
    var string = "criabto-";
    var criarCard = document.createElement("button");
    criarCard.setAttribute("type", "button");
    criarCard.setAttribute("id", string.concat(idContainer));
    criarCard.setAttribute("class", "criar-card");
    criarCard.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Criar Card'));
    var larguraetapa = document.querySelector("." + idContainer);
    larguraetapa.appendChild(criarCard);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const escutaClick = document.querySelector('.buttonNewCard');

escutaClick.addEventListener('click', function selecionaBotao(click) {
var idBotao = click.target.id;
var idContainer = idBotao.replace('bto-', '');
// Remove o botão Adicionar cartão
var btoAddCard = document.getElementById(idBotao);
btoAddCard.classList.add("invisivel");
//=============>Criar estrutura do card<===============
var { criarDiv, selecionarDiv } = criaDiv(idContainer);
criaCard(criarDiv, selecionarDiv);
CriaBto(idContainer);
});

//Cria elemento div
function criaDiv(idContainer) {
var selecionarDiv = document.getElementById(idContainer);
var criarDiv = document.createElement("div");
criarDiv.setAttribute("class", "card");
return { criarDiv, selecionarDiv };
}

// Cria elemento textarea
function criaCard(criarDiv, selecionarDiv) {
var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
textarea.setAttribute("class", "textCard");
textarea.setAttribute("placeholder", "Descreva a atividade");
textarea.setAttribute("onfocus", "this.selectionStart");
criarDiv.appendChild(textarea).focus();
selecionarDiv.appendChild(criarDiv);
}

//Remover Elementos 
function Remover(Card) {
const BotaoCriar = document.querySelector(".criar-card");
const BotaoAdicionarCartao = document.querySelector('.buttonNewCard');
Card.remove();
BotaoCriar.remove();
BotaoAdicionarCartao.classList.remove("invisivel");

}

//Posta o cartao criado
function PostarCard() {
const ContainerCards = document.querySelector('.containerCards');
const TextAreaConteudo = document.querySelector('.textCard');
const CriarCard = document.querySelector('.card');
if (TextAreaConteudo.value) {
    const p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerText = TextAreaConteudo.value;
    ContainerCards.appendChild(p);
    Remover(CriarCard);
} else {
    alert("voce deve Adicionar algo ao card")
}
}

// Criar botão Criar card
function CriaBto(idContainer) {
var string = "criabto-";
var criarCard = document.createElement("button");
criarCard.setAttribute("type", "button");
criarCard.setAttribute("id", string.concat(idContainer));
criarCard.setAttribute("class", "criar-card");
criarCard.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Criar Card'));
var larguraetapa = document.querySelector("." + idContainer);
larguraetapa.appendChild(criarCard);
criarCard.addEventListener("click", PostarCard);
}
```

adicionei duas funções uma para adicionar e outra para remover, eu editei pois estava adicionando varias classes no mesmo elemento, enfim voce estava na primeira linha pegando um elemento que nao tinha Aquela classe, nao tive o exato problema que voce descreveu e no meu pc funcionou de boa mas uma dica seria substituir os 'var' por 'let' ou 'const' pois talvez seja um problema de escopo, se mesmo assim nao resolver voce pode verificar os nomes das classes e dar varios console.log pelas funções nao é tao rapido mais funciona ou debugar no chrome

Comment: Obrigado nicolas, com uma etapa o seu código funciona perfeitamente, porém o caso é que  o sistema que estou desenvolvendo tem 7 etapas e nas demais etapas nem adiciona a div quando clico no botão adicionar cartão! Mas obrigado pela ajuda!!!

Comment: é justamente por esse motivo que eu criei as variáveis idBotao e idContainer, para passar o botão da etapa em que eu quero adicionar o card e adicionar o card na etapa em que eu estou clicando em adicionar cartão!

Comment: a sim entendo, voce nao teria esse codigo completo disponivel teria? voce disse que esta usando classes, e que na primeira etapa funciona mas nas demais nao, voce pode dar uma olhada no contexto do 'this'. mas se voce tiver o codigo no git hub seria mais facil tentar ajudar